# NXOpen, How to get first and last point3d of a dimension?

Tags: c#, dimension, nxopen

I'm trying to get the first and second point of a given dimension in NX draft.
Actually I tried this code:

```
var firstPoint3D = dimension.GetFirstAssociativity().FirstDefinitionPoint;
var SecondPoint3D = dimension.GetSecondAssociativity().FirstDefinitionPoint;
```

but the result always is 0,0,0 for both.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? If yes, do you have some more code?

Comment: The problem still exists, but we've changed our approach to resolve it, so we don't repeat these issues with this data as well.